# Where does the name "section" come from for a partially applied infix operator?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

In Haskell, we use the term "section" to indicate a partially applied function used in infix position. For instance, for a function `foo :: a -> b -> c` and values `x :: a` and `y :: b`, we have the two sections

```
s1 = (x `foo`) :: b -> c == \b -> foo x b
```

and

```
s2 = (`foo` y) :: a -> c == \a -> foo a y
```

In category theory, however, a section `g` of `f` is defined as a right inverse of `f` (so that `f . g == id`).

I don't see an obvious connection between the two definitions. For instance, `s1` is clearly not an inverse of `foo`, at least not in **Hask**. I suppose `s1` doesn't even have to *have* an inverse in **Hask**.

Is the category-theoretical definition the source of the Haskell definition, and if so, how?

Comment: My guess is that the two are completely unrelated. I interpret "section" as: you take `(x+y)`, chop off one part of it (take a "section"), and consider what remains.

Comment: That's so... prosaic, though.

Comment: I don't know, but I will try to find out.

Comment: The Miranda language had sections, and was designed by David Turner. Miranda strongly influenced the design of Haskell.

Comment: From the Miranda Manual, Chapter 9:  Acknowledgement:
 The idea of sections is due  to  Richard  Bird  (of  Oxford  University
Programming  Research Group) and David Wile (of USC Information Sciences Institute).  http://miranda.org.uk/

Comment: They appeared in Haskell 1.1, released Aug, 1991, according to 'A History of Haskell: Being Lazy With Class'

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, Haskell got the sections from Miranda (and Orwell).  David Turner says he got the idea from Richard Bird and David Wile.

I have just chatted with Richard Bird.  He says he doesn't remember where the name came from, but he thinks it was David Wile who coined it. Unfortunately, David Wile died last year, so we will probably never know.  But, Richard did admit that he was the one who convinced David Turner and Phil Wadler to add sections in their languages.

Here's the page from Wile's thesis that is the first know mention of "section".  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi6lK.jpg

Comment: Thanks for checking. I had never given it much thought, but so many other things are based in category theory it seemed possible this was as well.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly, it comes from "array section" operation, used primarily in Fortran, particularly for column or row extraction. That makes sense, if you consider making lookup table from two-argument function.
https://www.phy.ornl.gov/csep/pl/node16.html