# Is a function with a functional argument curried?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, currying

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/57020455/156458

> In Haskell, it happens that **everything is curried**; **all functions take just one argument** (even uncurried functions in Haskell take a tuple, which is, strictly speaking, a single argument -- you might want to play with the curry and uncurry functions to see how that works).

I am not sure if that is true, but assume so.

If a function takes another function as an argument, is it curried or uncurried in a similar sense as a function taking a tuple or list argument being uncurried? (A pair tuple type is `type1 x type2` and can be `type1^2`, while a function type is `type2^{type1}`, so I find them similar)

If uncurried, how can I convert such a function to a curried function?

Comment: A function is just one value that you can take as a parameter. Given that a function taking *one* other function as an argument, currying doesn't matter anyway if the function doesn't take multiple values?!

Comment: "*I find them similar*" - but they are not. Really not.

Comment: Currying is really about the isomorphism between the types `a -> b -> c` and `(a, b) -> c`. The curried form is more convenient, as it allows simpler use of partial application, and it "scales" better. The curry/uncurry isomorphism by itself doesn't convert something with type `a -> b -> c -> d` to something with type `(a, b, c) -> d`; it can only give you something with type `((a, b), c) -> d`. You need a second isomorphism to flatten `((a, b), c)` to `(a, b, c)`.

Comment: *"... while a function type is `type2^{type1}`"* no, the distinction is between `type3^(type1 x type2)` and `(type3^type2)^type1`. *"how to convert to a curried function"* [by using `curry`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57020745/849891). if `f` is "uncurried", `curry f` is "curried".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If a function takes another function as an argument, is it curried or uncurried?

It takes just a function, so a single parameter, and hence it is curried. The fact that that parameter is a function is irrelevant.

Such a function is for example `map`. `map` has type:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
```

It thus takes a single parameter, a function (of type `a -> b`), and then returns a function `[a] -> [b]` that will map a list of `a`s to a list of `b`s by applying that function.

So `map show :: Show a => [a] -> [String]` is the result of such function application, and this is again a function.

Comment: Thanks. Is it "uncurried" in a similar sense as a function taking a tuple or list argument being "uncurried"? If "uncurried", how can I convert such a function to a curried function?

Comment: @Tim No. A function is a single value. A tuple or lists consists of multiple values, that's the only reason why we would call a Haskell function "uncurried".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the quote is correct. All the talk about "curried" and "uncurried" *functions* is imprecise jargon.

Haskell is a curried *language*. Functions in Haskell always have exponential types. If an argument is a tuple, it doesn't matter, it is still just one value (which happens to be a tuple).

The concepts are approximated when we treat an `(a,b) -> c` Haskell function as the *c <sup>a * b</sup>* one. But it's just a mental gymnastics that we do.

What's actually curried or not, are *programming languages*. For instance, in Lisp,

```
(lambda (a b) c)
```

actually *has* the type *c <sup>a * b</sup>* and to turn it into the *(c <sup>b</sup>)<sup><sup>a</sup></sup>* function we need to put it through some transformations.

There actually is no `(\a b -> c)` lambdas in Haskell, only `(\ a -> (\ b -> c))` nested lambdas<sup>(</sup>*<sup>)</sup> . When we write `(\a b -> c)` in Haskell, it is just a syntactical shortcut for `(\ a -> (\ b -> c))`. It is impossible to have actual `(\a b -> c)` lambda function in Haskell, though it is approximated by having `(\(a,b) -> c)` lambda function.

Where you really see the meaning of all this, if when you implement your own language with lambda functions.

Faced with a `((lambda (a b) c) x y z)` function call, the real issue is *how to pair-up* the function's *parameters* and the *values* supplied.

Haskell converts it into `((let a=x in (let b=y in c)) z)`, but Lisp actually pairs up the parameters list `(a b)` with the list of values `(x y z)` and reports the length mismatch.

But, being the uncurried *language* that it is, Lisp is able to have the various twists and tweaks here, like optional arguments, default arguments, named arguments, etc., pairing up the parameters and the values in various different ways -- unlike Haskell, which *always* pairs up *one* parameter with *one* supplied value at a time.

---

<sup>(</sup>*<sup>)</sup> and with another crucial distinction: the `a` and `b` in Haskell's `(\ a -> (\ b -> c))` are not variables, but *patterns*. They are not just assigned the values, like in Lisp -- they are *matched up* with them.

Answer (score 2):

The truth I can see at least, is almost every value in haskell can be seen as a function with, and every function just take one parameter at the time. Let see an example (With Int as example, to be more clear):

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
f x y z = x + y + z
```

f can be seen as a function that takes a `Int` and returns a function

```
Int -> (Int -> Int)


:t (f 2)
(f 2) :: Int -> Int -> Int
:t (f 2 3)
(f 2 3) :: Int -> Int
```

(f 2 3) can be seen as a function that takes a `Int` and returns an `Int`

finally

```
:t (f 2 3 4)
(f 2 3 4) :: Int
```

An example with higher order functions:

```
h :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int -> Int
h fn x y = fn x y
```

A little more complex but just the same idea:

```
:t (h f)
(h f) :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
```

`(h f)` is a function, expecting an `Int` , and returning (Int -> Int -> Int -> Int)

but... wait, was not it expecting to return a function? it should be so

```
(h f) :: Int -> Int -> (Int -> Int)
```

well, point made. let's continue

```
:t (h f 2)
(h f 2) :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

`(h f 2)` is a function expecting a `Int` and returning a function (Int -> Int)

and finally

```
 :t (h f 2 3)
(h f 2 3) :: Int -> Int
```

`(h f 2 3)` indeed is a function, expecting a `Int`, returning an `Int`

```
(h f 2 3) 4 == 7
```

I think the conclusion here is, [every function is curried in Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying).

Comment: (1) Though this is largely correct, I believe a line should be drawn at the no arguments case. Ultimately, a Haskell function is something with `(->)` in its type, and so `3 :: Int` is not a function. (See also http://conal.net/blog/posts/everything-is-a-function-in-haskell ). I suggest simply dropping that case from this answer. (2) "Takes a `Num a` is not fully accurate, as `Num a` is not a type. "Takes an `a` (with `a` being an instance of `Num`)" is better. (3) On a related note, making `f` monomorphic (say, `f :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int`) would make your example more straightforward.

Comment: @duplode thanks a lot, I think it is more clear now, I've taken your advice